# Presenting cumulative average in time series

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to present a time series of a score to view the trend.

Score is an Average of all of the scores from the first Date in the table until the of the end of Year-Month.

ie. Jan 2018 = where date < Jan 2018
Feb 2018 = where date < Feb 2018

I would like to present this as a Monthly score for each Year-Month (Dec 2017, Jan 2018)

If score was not an average, i could utilize the Cumulative option in the Timeseries, however this does not work when introducing Avg(Metric).

I am really scratching my head on this one. Any advice on how to structure the data and present this in Google Datastudio would be greatly appreciated.

I have access to the database, and we are utilizing Big query to create the views.

Comment: Please include some sample data to your question, in tabular form, and then show what the expected output is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`avg()` should work.  Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       avg(val) over (partition by format_date('%Y%m', date))
from t;
```

Oops, this is the average for the current month.  If you want the running average:

```
select format_date('%Y%m', date) as yyyymm,
       (sum(sum(val)) over (order by min(date)) / 
        sum(count(*)) over (order by min(date))
       ) as running_avg
from t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

Comment: I have posted another question as a follow up for this. I am trying to add an additional group by. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160966/adding-additional-group-by-in-running-average